# JQUERY обращение к свойству DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Влез с редактурой в готовый скрипт js, но совсем безграмотен в этом.

как правильно обратиться к js, что нужно менять адреса картинок внутри `div` для свойства `style="background-image:url('http://...');"` а не просто для атрибута картинки `src="http://..."` ?

```
<img id="flash" src="http://1.png" style="position:fixed;" ><br>
<div id="go" style="margin-top:50vh;"></div>

<div id="flash" style="background-image:url('http://1.png');"></div>



<script>

    var images = [
        "https://1.png",
        "https://2.png",
        "https://3.png",
        "https://4.png"
    ];


     var obj = {curImg: 0};
     var tween = TweenMax.to(obj, 0.5,
     {
       curImg: images.length - 1,
       roundProps: "curImg",
       repeat: 0,                               
       immediateRender: true,           
       ease: Linear.easeNone,       
       onUpdate: function () {
          $("#flash").attr("src", images[obj.curImg]); 
       }
     }
     );


  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
  var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#go", duration: 500})
                    .setTween(tween)
                    .addTo(controller);
</script>
```

пробовал

```
$("#flash").attr(style: "background-image:url", images[obj.curImg]);
```

и опускал в коде триггер, но не сработало

Answer (score 3):

[Документация по .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$("#flash").css('background-image', 'url(' + images[obj.curImg] + ')');
```